# Using Motion in CosmicMind's Material

Tags: swift3, cosmicmind

When i try to use CosmicMind's motion animation framework, I receive an error whenever I try an example. For example, taken straight from the Sample's repo:

```
    dateLabel.animate(.delay(1),
                         .duration(0.5),
                         .background(color: Color.cyan.base),
                         .completion({ [weak self] in

                            self?.dateLabel.animate(.delay(1),
                                                       .duration(0.5),
                                                       .background(color: Color.deepPurple.base))
                         }))
```

throws the error 'Extra argument in call'

I can't animate anything because I always receive this error. What can i do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem, did you find the solution in Animations Project?

Comment: I just updated material and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had tested the animation with [Material 2.8.1](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.8.1) and all worked correctly. Please make sure you are using the latest Material version. All the best!